# Symfony 2.7+ Asset Custom Version Strategy config

Tags: symfony, assets, symfony-2.7

I have successfully set up my Symfony 2.7.x installation to use standard Asset Version Strategies (EmptyVersionStrategy and StaticVersionStrategy) but would like to implement a [Custom Version Strategy](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/asset/introduction.html#custom-version-strategies) like a date-based strategy or similar.

currently, I have

*config.yml*

```
framework:
    assets:
        version: 'v1' # or ~ for EmptyVersionStrategy
```

**Since the `version` value seems to implement the strategy and also the value, how do I configure a custom strategy?**

I have already read the [Asset Blog article](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-the-new-asset-component) and the [less-than-complete docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/asset/introduction.html).

Comment: I found [this symfony ticket](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/15554) which essentially outlines the same problem but provides no solution as yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace `EmptyVersionStrategy` by ease, just override the service as you can see below:

**app/config/services.yml**

```
services:
    assets.empty_version_strategy:
        class:      FooBundle\Twig\Extension\AssetVersionStrategy
        arguments:  ["%kernel.root_dir%"]
```

**src/FooBundle\Twig\AssetVersionStrategy.php**

```
namespace FooBundle\Twig\Extension;

use Symfony\Component\Asset\VersionStrategy\VersionStrategyInterface;


/**
 * AssetVersionStrategy (Twig)
 *
 * @author Your Name <you@example.org>
 * @license MIT License (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)
 */
class AssetVersionStrategy implements VersionStrategyInterface
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $root;

    /**
     * @param string $root
     */
    public function __construct($root)
    {
        $this->root = $root;
    }

    /**
     * Should return the version by the given path (starts from public root)
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @return string
     */
    public function getVersion($path)
    {
        return $path;
    }

    /**
     * Determines how to apply version into the given path
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @return string
     */
    public function applyVersion($path)
    {
        return sprintf('%s?v=%s', $path, $this->getVersion($path));
    }
}
```